# REALTEK RTL8187 Wireless LAN Driver and Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: networking, drivers, realtek

Old problem in the new operating system:

1. I have an ASUS motherboard with a built-in wi-fi card, the operating system is Ubuntu 19.10, all network drivers are standard
2. periodically, the connection to the wi-fi network is disconnected, the card ceases to see all networks
3. I turn off and turn on the wi-Fi card, everything starts working again
4. I saw a lot of tickets on many sites, but almost all of them concern wi-fi cards with other chipsets, or they are 10-12 years old, different Linux operating systems, and so on

5 I’m thinking about making a script that will turn off and turn on the Wi-Fi card and the disappearance of ping, but this is too strange

6. Is there any new way to solve this problem? new old drivers?

Comment: Use iwlist scan to find your signal strength, and the strengths/channels of all your neighbors. Change channels, reorient your access point antenna, etc. if you have a signal weaker than other on your channel.

Comment: the problem is not in the busy channel, in the network manager of the operating system itself all other networks disappear, only turning off and on helps

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by disabling the quick boot option in the BIOS of the motherboard